# JSON output not showing in console log

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a notification button for an inactive article for my blog and I don't want admin to reload his/her page to see a new inactive article submitted so I want to do this with Ajax, but, I am very new to ajax. I have fetched the data from the database and have stored in JSON in filename called file.php, here is my code:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/init.php';

require CLASS_PATH.'article.php';

$article = new Article();

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$list = $article->getInactiveArticle();

echo json_encode($list);
```

I have written the following lines of code for Ajax:

```
    <script>
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'file.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response)
    {
        if (response != 0 ) {
            if (typeof(response) != "object") {
                response = $.parseJSON(response);
                console.log(response);
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I am not getting anything in the console though there is data in JSON. What should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not getting anything in the console though there is data in JSON.

Where `$.ajax()` `type` is set to `"json"` the first argument at `callback` is a JavaScript plain object, not a `JSON` string.

> What should be done?

Remove `if` statements and use `console.log(response)`. `JSON.parse()` is not necessary.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'file.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
})
```

Comment: I didn't get this: Where $.ajax() type is set to "json" the first argument at callback is a JavaScript plain object, not a JSON string.

Comment: @Alisha `function(response) {console.log(response)}` is the function value for `success` property: _"A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the `dataType` parameter.."_, `dataType`: _"The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback):"_ , _"`"json"`: Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object."_ See [jQuery.ajax( \[settings \] )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)